# Recommendations for Building a Linux Laptop on a Budget

Tags: laptop, linux

Looking to build a laptop, though would consider buying a pre-built.

My requirements are:

```
1) $300 - $500 price tag
2) Linux OS (Debian or Ubuntu)
3) Decent Processing 
4) Light Weight/ low profile
```

This doesn't need to be super computer. I'm mainly looking for something to play around with programming and some statistical analysis. This would also be a chance to step into the realms of a full blown linux distribution. Trying to get off the microsoft/apple bandwagons as my experience with their products continue to get worse and worse every year. Additionally I have become a big fan of Linux though my experience is limited.

I will consider buying a pre built but do enjoy tinkering with RaspberryPis and would enjoy the project of assembly and modification.

I use a Dell for work and have been very happy, but I have no preference on brand.

A bonus here would be the ability to upgrade down the road. Ease of compatibility would also be a plus, but may not even be something worth heavy consideration.

Comment: Well, I am running an MSI gaming laptop (low end, cost me 1kUSD last August, needed a new system for fall semester.  Now it is around....near half that.   Had a few issues with GPU/dGPU when I tried installing Debian for one course.  Apparently the older kernel did not take kindly to the system having both a low power, and a high power GPU in the system (Optimus System in my case)   Newer kernels have addressed that for the most part.  I will look into systems in the morning, I am totally exhausted.  Unpaid internships are evil.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend:  [Acer Laptop Aspire E5-553G](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834315445&ignorebbr=1)

This is within budget restrictions @ $459.99 (199.99 @ off newegg until 2/1/2017)

8GB ram can be upgraded to 32Gb

Weight is 5.27Lbs

It does come with windows 10 (use a Debian/Ubuntu LiveUSB and install over it)

128Gb SSD (OS drive usually)

1Tb HDD (only 5400rpm, may want to upgrade to 7200rpm or another SSD)

Dimensions:  15.02" x 10.20" x 0.94"-1.19"

1 x USB 3.1 Type-C

2 x USB 3.0 (1 with Power-off Charging)

1 x USB 2.0

1 x HDMI Port with HDCP support

1 x Docking Connector

1 x Headphone/Speaker/Line-Out Jack